# Is there a way with concurrency, that a same Object.equals(Object) returns false?

Tags: java, concurrency, equals

That's something that pestered my mind one of this days, so I am looking for a concrete answer.

(please, bear with me, I am not looking to make a beautiful code. Au contraire, I'm lookng for a problem with code that smell)

Imagine we have a stateful Object comming from class `Foo`

```
public class Foo {
     public int attribute = 0;

     // hashCode implemented :P
     @Override
     public boolean equals(Object o) {
         if (o instanceof Foo) {
            Foo that = (Foo) o;

            return this.attribute == that.attribute;
         }
         return false;
     }
}
```

And we have some workers on Foo

```
public class DoomBringer implements Runnable {

    private final Foo foo;

    public DoomBringer(Foo foo) {
        this.foo = foo;
    }
    @Override
    public void run() {
       this.foo.attribute++;
    }
}
```

And another one that only prints the result of `#equals` for the object passed as parameter to its constructor.

```
public class SelfEqualityTestPrinter implements Runnable {

    private final Foo foo;

    public SelfEqualityTestPrinter(Foo foo) {
        this.foo = foo;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println(foo.equals(foo));
    }
}
```

**Is it possible that `false` will be printed one day if we have concurrent threads modifying the same `Foo` instance?**

My guess is that it's possible. I don't think equals is synchronized unless we make it so. A way to avoid this would be testing `this == o` at the `Object#equals(Object o)` method, but the same problem may rise from comparing different instances that should be equal.

Comment: Since `Foo` isn't threadsafe in regard to `attribute` nor does it safely publish `attribute` ... all bets are off, period, when talking about concurrency.

Comment: Note that `this.foo.attribute++` isn't even guaranteed to increment `attribute` (in effect)! That is, it's possible for two threads to execute `attribute++` and yet for it only to be incremented once. This is a classic race condition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, its possible. Any variables that are not synchronized can be changed at any moment by any thread given access to those variables.

If access to `foo.attribute` was synchronized, and `.equals` was synchronized when referencing `attribute`, this would not be the case.

More surprising, if one thread changed `attribute`, another thread could read it afterwards and get its old value! This last piece can be fixed through the use of the volatile keyword. Here's a good [explanation of the volatile keyword](http://jeremymanson.blogspot.com/2008/11/what-volatile-means-in-java.html).

As Brian and yshavit have said,  problems in not declaring a variable volatile include race conditions. Here, for example, 2 threads calling `attribute++` could result in `attribute` only being incremented once. The second thread to increment could use the unincremented value for `attribute` stored in his cached memory instead of the incremented value written by the first thread.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, in the presence of concurrent modifications it is entirely possible that `foo.equals(foo)` will return `false`. One way to address this is to think who reads and modifies what, and to synchronize accordingly.

Comment: Worth mentioning is that it's unlikely any modification to `attribute` will be seen by any other thread since it's not `volatile`

Comment: @BrianRoach - that's not entirely accurate.  in many cases, non-thread-safe changes _are_ visible to other threads, that's what makes the lack of thread-safety so insidious.  it's when you get heavy production loads that you start to see heavy thread local caching.

Comment: It's well defined how visibility occurs. And that's not even mentioning post-increment is *not* an atomic operation.

Comment: @BrianRoach You are correct in how visibility is defined, but you have overstated the case by saying it is "unlikely" that the modifications will be seen.  Practically, non-volatile writes are seen by non-synchronized threads most of the time, there are just no guarantees that this will be the case (and so of course you should never depend on it).

Comment: I think you're overstating "most of the time" since the classic example is changing a boolean flag from another thread to stop a loop in a `Runnable` ... and have it not work. ;) That said, I find no harm in overstating the right way to do something in a short comment. The OP should really be encouraged to buy the JCIP book for a formal reference.